# Time complexity of nested loops with index carried along

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity

Consider these three functions, which should do exactly the same. The vector `v` is sorted from small to big values and `lower < upper`.

```
long long count1(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        count += std::upper_bound(begin(v)+i, end(v), v[i] + upper)
                -std::lower_bound(begin(v)+i, end(v), v[i] + lower);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I expect `count1` to be O(n*log(n)), due to the binary search in each iteration.

```
long long count2a(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    int n = v.size(), l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (l < n && v[l] - v[i] < lower) ++l;
        while (r < n && v[r] - v[i] <= upper) ++r;
        count += r - l;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I expect `count2a` to be O(n), because `l` and `r` are shifted at most `n` times.

```
long long count2b(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    int n = v.size(), l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (l < n && v[l] - v[i] < lower) ++l;
        r = l; // new line
        while (r < n && v[r] - v[i] <= upper) ++r;
        count += r - l;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I expect `count2b` to be O(n) but faster than `count2a`, because it potentially skips the first iterations of the second while loop and `l <= r`, always.

A benchmark, however, shows relations of `time = n^a * const` with `a = 1.1, 0.9, 2.0`, respectively.

[image]

Why does the runtime of `count2b` scale quadratically with `n`?

Minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

long long count1(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        count += std::upper_bound(begin(v)+i, end(v), v[i] + upper)
                -std::lower_bound(begin(v)+i, end(v), v[i] + lower);
    }
    return count;
}
long long count2a(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    int n = v.size(), l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (l < n && v[l] - v[i] < lower) ++l;
        while (r < n && v[r] - v[i] <= upper) ++r;
        count += r - l;
    }
    return count;
}
long long count2b(std::vector<int> const& v, int lower, int upper) {
    long long count = 0;
    int n = v.size(), l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (l < n && v[l] - v[i] < lower) ++l;
        r = l;
        while (r < n && v[r] - v[i] <= upper) ++r;
        count += r - l;
    }
    return count;
}

void benchmark(int r, std::ostream& os, auto&& func, auto&&... args) {
    long long test = 0;
    std::vector<long long> times;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        test += func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        times.push_back((double)duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count());
    }
    double mean = 0, sd = 0;
    for (auto& d : times) {
        mean += d;
    }
    mean /= times.size();
    for (auto& d : times) {
        sd += pow((d - mean), 2);
    }
    sd = sqrt(sd / times.size());

    os << mean << " " << sd << " ";
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}

void main() {
    std::mt19937 reng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 1e8);
    std::ofstream file("bench.txt");
    for (int n = 100; n < 1e5; n *= 1.1) {
        int r = 2;

        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

        std::vector<int> v(n);
        for (auto& a : v) a = d(reng);
        std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
        int lower = d(reng), upper = lower + d(reng);

        file << n << " ";
        benchmark(r, file, &count1, v, lower, upper);
        file << std::endl;
        file << n << " ";
        benchmark(r, file, &count2a, v, lower, upper);
        file << std::endl;
        file << n << " ";
        benchmark(r, file, &count2b, v, lower, upper);
        file << std::endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `count2b` to be O(n)? There's an outer loop of n iterations and the two inner loops of approx. n-count iterations.

Comment: I am not sure. I think just as `count2a`, the body of the while loops are executed at most `n` times because `l` and `r` can not be shifted beyond `n`.

Comment: suppose this is right "the body of the while loops are executed at most n times ", then multiply it by `n` for the outer for loop and you have `n^2` not `n`

Comment: They are shifted at most n times in total. During the entire function call. l and r are never reset, they are "carried along".

Comment: Well, in count 2b you potentially reset `r`. It could be that for every iteration of the outer loop the condition of the first while loop is never satisfied (i.e. `l` remains `0`) and the condition of the second while loop is always satisfied and it is always iterated to `n` and in the next iteration of the for loop `r` is reset to `0` again. This question would be a lot easier to answer if you provided an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What happens if you have `r = max(l, r);` instead of `r = l;`?

Comment: Yes, that is it! I thought `r = l` can only save iterations, but it often resets `r` too far back.  `r=max(l,r)` deals with it (has no advantage over `count2a` though).